# How to generate different random number not identical?

Tags: javascript

I need to get number not identical by twice compare. first it will check equal with condition 1. if not equal. it will check again second condition.

prediction2d contains 12 numbers: 54,87,85,62,41,32,56,48,72,76,65,35

First while check if length under 8. and compare prediction2d with random number. at now. it goes what i want. but, how about i want to compare it again. randomnumber with additionalnumber. after that it will push to addtional number.

the random number sometime output same number that already have in additionalNumber array. how to make it not identical.

```
var additionalNumber = [];
while(additionalNumber.length < 8){
    length = additionalNumber.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        var randomNumber = controlNumber(10, 99);

        if(randomNumber != prediction2d[i]){
          additionalGroup.layers[length].textItem.contents = 
          randomNumber;
          additionalNumber.push(randomNumber);
          break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if a value is already in an array.

```
const prediction2d = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22];
const additionalNumber = [];

while(additionalNumber.length < 8) {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * (99 - 10 + 1)) + 10);
    if (! additionalNumber.includes(randomNumber)) {
        if (! prediction2d.includes(randomNumber)) {
            additionalNumber.push(randomNumber);
        }  
    }
}
console.log(additionalNumber);
```

You could also use [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).